# $OPENMP_FFLAGS not working in autoconf

Tags: fortran, openmp, gfortran, autotools

I am trying to compile a fortran code with `gnu-autotools`. The openmp specific lines in `configure.ac` is:

```
AC_PROG_FC([gfortran])
AC_OPENMP
FCFLAGS="$OPENMP_FCFLAGS -fcheck=all"
```

If I compile with this, I am not getting `omp` related compiler options, as described in the  AC_OPENMP macro in [autoconf manual](https://www.gnu.org/software/autoconf/manual/autoconf-2.67/html_node/Generic-Compiler-Characteristics.html).

If I explicitly place `-fopenmp` in place of `$OPENMP_FFLAGS`, only then its working.

Any help please?

Comment: How about `$OPENMP_FCFLAGS`?

Comment: No change...its still not picking up OPENMP_FCFLAGS

Comment: I don't really understand autotools, but shouldn't the `AC_OPENMP` line be **after** `AC_PROG_FC([gfortran])`? Given that the latter most likely sets the Fortran compiler, one would expect that the OpenMP detection must be performed after the compiler was set, not before.

Comment: yes...you are right...and I have done that already. But that does not effect the result

Comment: Do you get any error messages? What does `configure` say when you run it?

Comment: What about [AX_OPENMP](https://www.gnu.org/software/autoconf-archive/ax_openmp.html), would it work ?

Answer (score 1):

Autoconf typically likes testing everything for C language by default and that's why you're only getting `$OPENMP_CFLAGS` as a result for the `AC_OPENMP` command. However, Autoconf also provides mechanisms to change the programming language (and therefore the compiler also) by using the `AC_LANG` command (please, take a look at [Autoconf / Language Choice webpage](https://www.gnu.org/software/autoconf/manual/autoconf-2.63/html_node/Language-Choice.html) for further details and also some alternatives).

The following code has been tested using the command autoconf 2.69 and using the command: `autoreconf -fiv` (also using an empty Makefile.am file).

```
AC_INIT([omp-fortran-sample], [1.0])
AC_PROG_CC
AC_PROG_FC([gfortran])

dnl Checks for OpenMP flag for C language, stores it in $OPENMP_CFLAGS
AC_LANG(C)
AC_OPENMP

dnl Checks for OpenMP flag for Fortran language, stores it in $OPENMP_FCFLAGS
AC_LANG(Fortran)
AC_OPENMP

AC_CONFIG_HEADERS([config.h])
AC_CONFIG_FILES([Makefile])
AC_OUTPUT
```

The resulting execution of the configure shows two tests for OpenMP as seen here:

```
checking for gcc option to support OpenMP... -fopenmp
checking for gfortran option to support OpenMP... -fopenmp
```

And Makefile now includes both `OPENMP_CFLAGS` and `OPENMP_FCFLAGS` definitions, among the rest, as shown below:

```
...
MKDIR_P = /bin/mkdir -p
OBJEXT = o
OPENMP_CFLAGS = -fopenmp
OPENMP_FCFLAGS = -fopenmp
PACKAGE = omp-fortran-sample
...
```